# Unity отключение освещения

Tags: unity3d

Как можно отключать полностью освещение во время игры? Но только отключать не в том смысле, что на сцене будет темно, а в том смысле, что не будет никакого освещения в принципе - ни теней, ни лучей.
Подобное я могу сделать лишь в scene, нажимая на кнопку со знаком лампочки[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `отключать [свет] не в том смысле, что на сцене будет темно, а в том смысле, что не будет никакого освещения` - я боюсь, что в нашем мире это невозможно) Основываясь на моем жизненном опыте, обычно там, где нет света, становится темно, я могу ошибаться. А вообще, если хотите выключать свет, то в чем проблема отключить его через SetActive(false); ?

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нужно в уже собранной игре, добавить возможность включать и выключать освещение - это нужно для художника. Такое возможно? Нужного мне эффекта я могу добить лишь в редакторе сцены, нажав на лампочку, но как такое сделать в самой игре?

Answer (score 0):

В редакторе во вкладке **Scene view** - окно где происходит редактирование сцен - можно отключить освещение нажав копку в левом верхнем углу со значком **лампочки**.

Если нужно сделать то же самое но, с компонентами и в удобном редакторе для освещения тогда **Window/Rendering/LightExplorer** все удобства для дизайнера.

Если нужно сделать тоже самое но, в **PlayMode** в редакторе или в сборке, понадобиться немного терпения :

```
        var _sceneLights = FindObjectsOfType<Light>();
        foreach (var ligth in _sceneLights) // обрабатываем все источники освещения
        {
            ligth.enabled = true; // true включить, false выключить.
            ligth.color = Color.red; // применить цвет 
            ligth.intensity = 100f; // применить интенсивность            
        }
```

Находим список объектов **Light** - производный класс всех источников освещения (возможно всех), и начинаем изменять - за один кадр. Допустим вы могли бы вывести себе далее некий **Editor** для некоторых общих манипуляций но, **LightExplorer** все равно лучше.